# "Skype for Business StatsMan PerfAgent" causing "The Open Procedure for service XXX in DLL ZZZ failed"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, perfmon, performance-counters, skype-for-business-2016

We followed the Microsoft article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/mt604835.aspx) and installed the "Skype for Business StatsMan PerfAgent" on our Skype for Business server. The product is working as expected but every 10 min the PerfAgent.exe service (running as Network Service as set by the installer) try to access some registry values where he do not have rights to (seen via ProcMon). This caused that the following errors:

```
Unable to open the Server service performance object. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status code.

The Open Procedure for service "WmiApRpl" in DLL "C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

The Open Procedure for service "BITS" in DLL "C:\Windows\System32\bitsperf.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

The Open Procedure for service ".NETFramework" in DLL "C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.
```

are logged in the eventlog. If the stop the "Skype for Business StatsMan PerfAgent" service the errors will not be recorded. Compared that this happen every 10min there are many hundred entries per day recorded. Any idea what might caused that issue? We followed exactly the article from Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

For WmiApRpl problems on Skype servers that use Skype StatsMan, you need to add Full Control permissions to (local) NETWORK SERVICE on this registry node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WmiApRpl\Performance\
```

After that restart the StatsMan service.

For BITS it's this node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BITS\Performance
```

For .NETFramework it's this node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\.NETFramework\Performance
```

Don't forget to restart StasMan service afterwards